# Custom "types" in JSON (node/express) and JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, c#, json, node.js, schema

I recently had to convert a project that had a lot of work done with ASP.NET Core 1.0 to Node.js. I'm absolutely out of my comfort zone, knowing hardly anything about JavaScript and having had the good life of ASP serializing C# classes for me without me having to do the JSON myself. Node wants me to do the JSON myself which I am having a bad time with.

It's a fitness app. You have clients with some progress containing their lifts and stuff. In C#, that is in a Workouts object, as seen below:

```
    public struct Progress
    {
        public Workout[] Workouts;
    }
```

Workouts is a re-usable object containing things like timing, sets, repetitions, all the good stuff. I could just re-write the Workouts object in every single one of my schemas that need it, but there must be a better way? I read something about `$schema` and `$ref` but am unfamiliar with how to use them or if this is the right application of those keywords.

Lastly, how would I define an array of this custom Workout object?

This is my JSON object and the contents of `client.js` so far. The progress bit is the thing that I'd ideally like to achieve.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    measurements: [{
        height: Number,
        weight: Number
    }],
    personal_information: [{
        birthday: Date,
        gender: String
    }],
    contact_information: [{
        phone: String,
        email: String
    }],
    progress: [{
        workouts: WorkoutList
    }]
});
```

Comment: Are you asking if one schema can use another schema for embedded documents?

Comment: @JasonCust maybe? I'm using the Workouts schema in a few different other schemas so I'd like to avoid writing it again and again in the different schemas and just call like "progress: Workout," sort of thing. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on if you expect the same data to be included in the different schemas or if you just want the same structure. For instance given a document created from `ClientSchema` that includes a `client.progress[].workouts` sub-document, would the data represented by this sub-document only need to be accessible from this particular client document or would it also need to be a sub-document in another document (client or otherwise)?

Comment: @JasonCust I'd really just like to copy the structure. The progress data will be different for each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a common data structure that can be used in various other models then you can create a [sub-doc schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) (that may or may never have its own model) that will be used by various other schemas.

*NOTE: This provides a singleton schema object which means if you were to modify it one model it would be propagated to any other models that later use it. If that is a concern than you can convert `workout-list-schema.js` to be a factory function that would return a new schema object each time.*

**workout-list-schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WorkoutListSchema = module.exports.WorkoutListSchema = new Schema({
  // some schema
});
```

**client-schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var WorkoutListSchema = require('./workout-list-schema').WorkoutListSchema;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ClientSchema = new Schema({
  measurements: [{
    height: Number,
    weight: Number
  }],
  personal_information: [{
    birthday: Date,
    gender: String
  }],
  contact_information: [{
    phone: String,
    email: String
  }],
  progress: [{
    workouts: WorkoutListSchema
  }]
});
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Do you know how to make the workoutlist schema be an actual list (like an array of workouts)?

Comment: @KingDan I'm not sure what you mean but if you are referring to `workouts` being a list then you can edit the schema to be: `workouts: [WorkoutListSchema]`.

Comment: that is absolutely what I wanted. You're a total gem. Thank you :)